# Altering a structure variable with an "if" statement C++

Tags: c++, struct

I have a homework assignment due tomorrow that wants us to prompt the user to enter in a number of cars, the miles driven on them, then display the total cost. The cost is dependent upon the amount of miles; if it's less than 100, it's 25 cents/miles and if it's more than 100 the cost is 100 + 15 cents/mile. I created a structure that holds `Miles` and `Price`. Here is what I have so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Cars
{
    int Miles;
    double Price;
};

int main()
{    
    cout << "ENTER ALL OF THE CARS!";
    int NoCars;
    cin >> NoCars;
    Cars* info = new Cars[NoCars];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<NoCars; i++)
    {
        cout << "How many miles were driven on this car? :";
        cin >> info[i].Miles;
        if(Miles > 100)
        {
            Price = 25 + 0.15 * Miles;
        } 
        else 
        {
            Price = 0.25*Miles;
        }
    }
    cout << "Here are the prices: \n";
    for(x=0, x < NoCars; x++)
    {
        cout << info[x].Price;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I tried modifying the `Price` variable with an `if` statement, but it doesn't seem I can access it that simply. Any pointers?

Comment: Price is inside the struct Cars.  You can't access it "simply".  (And yes, you need to use pointers.)

Comment: `Price` is a member of the `Cars` struct, you can't just say `Price` and expect the compiler to know which one you mean. Same for `Miles` (which you access correctly to set it)

Comment: You get the access right here: `info[i].Miles` but then wrong on the next line: `if(Miles > 100)`!

Comment: By the way, industry-standard coding convention is to use leadingLowerCase for variable and method names, while reserving LeadingUpperCase for struct names, class names, and (some) constants.

Comment: That's Java coding convention not C++

Comment: @JohnSmith - That would be news to about a million programmers.

Comment: You're leaking memory `Cars* info = new Cars[NoCars];`. That's a quick way to lose marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Price` and `Miles` are fields of `struct Cars`, so you need to use them like this:

```
if(info[i].Miles > 100)
{
    info[i].Price = 25 + 0.15 * info[i].Miles;
} 
else 
{
    info[i].Price = 0.25 * info[i].Miles;
}
```

Also, in the last `for` statement, you are using `x` which is not declared, perhaps a typo of `i`? BTW, you lost a semicolon there, too:

```
for(x=0, x < NoCars; x++)
//     ^ should be ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are few mistakes in this little program:

```
1:if(Miles > 100)
    {
        Price = 25 + 0.15 * Miles;
    } 
    else 
    {
        Price = 0.25*Miles;
    }
```

Maybe you should change that like this:

```
if(info[i].Miles > 100)
    {
        info[i].Price = 25 + 0.15 * info[i].Miles;
    } 
    else 
    {
        info[i].Price = 0.25*info[i].Miles;
    }
```

2:`for(x=0, x < NoCars; x++)`

Maybe you should change that like this:

```
for(x=0; x < NoCars; x++)
```